# Stagehand doesn't support Dart 2.3.1 error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I got a "Dart upgrade" in VS Code (win10)
right after when I try to create a new flutter web project
I got

> Unable to execute Stagehand. Stagehand exited with code 65. stagehand 3.3.2 doesn't support Dart 2.3.1.

given that I didn't have this problem before,
I'm assuming that it's caused by the update.

I run "flutter upgrade" and this is my flutter doctor

> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
> [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.4, on Microsoft Windows
> [Version 10.0.18362.295], locale en-US)
>
> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 28.0.3) [√] Android Studio (version 3.4) [√] VS Code, 64-bit
> edition (version 1.38.0) [!] Connected device
> ! No devices available
>
> ! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

and this is my "flutter --version"

> Flutter 1.7.8+hotfix.4 • channel stable •
> https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git Framework • revision 20e59316b8
> (7 weeks ago) • 2019-07-18 20:04:33 -0700 Engine • revision fee001c93f
> Tools • Dart 2.4.0

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running

> pub global activate stagehand

allows it to work again.